# JitBit Helpdesk API

Tags: authentication, http-headers

Wondering if anyone else is using the JitBit Helpdesk software and their API

https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/helpdesk-api/

We are unable to authenticate to the interface as it returns a 401 every time. I'm not sure if we are setting the headers incorrectly or if we need to enable something in the ticketing software to allow us access.

https://www.programmableweb.com/api/jitbit-helpdesk/sample-source-code

We've tried connecting through node and python and receive the same results. Here is an example of what i'm using through node

```js
const options = {
        url: 'https://helpdesk/api/Authorization',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from('Domain\\username' + ":" + 'password').toString('base64')
        }
}
    
function callback(error, response, body) {

    console.log(response)

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const info = JSON.parse(body);          
        console.log('success',info)
    }

}
      
request(options,callback)
```

I had to set the rejectUnauthorized to false, it was saying it couldn't return the certificate (UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY). Not sure if that could be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it resolved. We had anonymous access disabled. It was recommend by support to have this enabled otherwise you'll run into issues such as authenticating to the API.

Comment: Just to help clarify - this is "Anonymous Authentication" at the IIS Level